# Run Javascript in iFrame context

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, nw.js

I am attempting to run a script in a webpage, that should be executed in an `<iframe>`.  Right now I can call a function that is set within the `<iframe>`..  I'm just having issues running a script to the `<iframe>`'s context.

Here's how I run a function set in the `<iframe>`

```
$('#iframe').get(0).contentWindow.performSearch();
```

Now instead of calling the `preformSearch` function, I wish to run a script - for this example, this is the script...

```
console.log('worked!');
```

My actual script is a big one, so I won't put it here - for the sake of this question.

So, is there any way to run that script through the `<iframe>`'s context?  For example, my first guess would be/was..

```
$('#iframe').get(0).contentWindow.function(){
 console.log('worked!');
}
```

I've never messed with running functions through something like an `<iframe>` before though, so I'm stumped.

Thanks for any help in advance!

**NOTE** I am using NW.js (Node-Webkit) to remove all `<iframe>` restrictions.

**NOTE v2 The `preformSearch()` function was just a reforence on how I call functions in the frame.**

Comment: Is function using jQuery? If so can't really bind the function to new window directly or `iframeWindow.jQuery` will be undefined. But can easily pass `window` as argment of function....show sample of function itself

Comment: You have to have `performSearch` as a function on the page which the iframe comes from for that to work.

Comment: You have to have `performSearch` as a function on the page which the iframe comes from for that to work.

Comment: That function works, but it was just an example on how to call functions to the `<iframe>`.  I'm trying to insert a script now, not a function.  (preformSearch was already set on the page the `<iframe>` was viewing, my new code is not.)

Answer (score 0):

You could try and use the messaging mechanizm
which means that on the parent frame you could send the message with

```
    var win =$("#iframe").contentWindow;
    win.postMessage({ messageType: "predefinedMessage", features: data }, '*');
```

and than in the iframe you could get the message

```
    function FrameCommunicator(attachManager) {
    var mfilesFrame;
    function _actOnMessage(data) {
        if (data.messageType === "predefinedMessage") {
        //perform here what you need
        }
    }

    window.addEventListener("message", function (e) {
        var data = e.data;
        mfilesFrame = e.source;
        _actOnMessage(data);
    }, false);

}
```

now the thing is that the iframe and the parent fram can have the same code if they reference to the  remotely.

Another way would be just to send the content of the message as JS and run it with eval , but that is risky , bad practice and lotsa other things :)

Comment: Beautiful answer, but unfortunately can't do what I want.  I don't have access to the iFrame's code.

Comment: `onmessage` is not supported by IE. Since most Browsers on the market are IE, unfortunately  this is not a good idea anyways.

Comment: I'm using node-webkit, so as long as it works in Chrome, that's all I need.